# Showing that $\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x^2+4y^2\le 1\}$ is connected

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, proof-verification

Let $E :=\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2:  x^2+4y^2\le 1\}$. Then there do not exist any two sets $A$ and $B$, such that $A$ and $B$ are relatively open in $E$ and $A\cup B = E$, since $E$ is closed. Hence, $E$ is connected.

Do you think this argument is rigorous and sufficient?

Comment: No, I don't think so.  It sounds like you just stated the definition of connectedness with no actual analysis of the set.

Comment: Do you need do it by definition?

Comment: You could very easily argue that it is path-connected, by showing that there is a continuous path to zero from any point $p\in E$ We could define it by $f(t)=p\cdot (1-t)$ and it is easy to say that from $p\in E$, $f(t)\in E$ follows for all $t\in [0,1]$.

Comment: @sinbadh: yes, by definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume the contrary that there are two relatively open sets $A, B$, $A, B \neq \emptyset, E$, $A\cap B  =\emptyset$ and $A \cup B = E$. Let $x\in A, y\in B$. consider $\gamma : [0,1] \to E$, 
$$\gamma (t) = (1-t)x + ty.$$ 
Note as $E$ is convex, $\gamma(t) \in E$ for all $t$. Note also that $\gamma$ is continuous. Now

$$C = \gamma^{-1}(A), D = \gamma^{-1}(B)$$

are two disjoint nonempty open sets in $[0,1]$ so that $C\cup D = [0,1]$. But that contradicts the facts that $[0,1]$ is connected (Do you know why?). Thus $A, B$ does not exists and so $E$ is connected.

(Of course, I am just proving that path connectedness implies connectedness here)

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to read about what a convex set means first.

Comment: @sequence: Convexity is not essential here. The main point is that every two points in $E$ can be joined by a continuous path $\gamma$ (It just happens that I can choose a straight path, since $E$ is convex).

Comment: John: How is $\gamma^{-1}(A)$ defined exactly? If $\gamma(t)$ operates with two points $x$ and $y$, and $y\not\in A$, then what is $\gamma^{-1}(x)$, where $x\in A$?

Comment: That's the preimage. In general if $f:X\to Y$ is a mapping and $B \subset Y$, then $f^{-1}(B) = \{x\in X: f(x) \in B\}$. @sequence. $x, y\in E$ are fixed already. The domain of $\gamma$ is $[0,1]$.

Comment: But because $x$ and $y$ are fixed, how does $\gamma^{-1}(A)$ operate? $A$ consists of all points $x$.

Comment: Note $\gamma^{-1} (A) = \{ t\in [0,1] : \gamma(t) = (1-t) x+ ty \in A\}$. $x, y$ are fixed. @sequence

Comment: So is $\gamma(t) \in A$ only for $t=0$? Otherwise, since $y\in B$, $\gamma(t)\not\in A$?

Comment: You do not know. it might happen that $\gamma(t) \in A$ for $t$ small.... All we know is that $\gamma^{-1}(A)$, $\gamma^{-1}(B)$ are both open and $\gamma^{-1}(A) \cup \gamma^{-1}(B)  =[0,1]$. @sequence

Comment: I think I got it, just realized that we're talking about a line segment which is in $A$. I misinterpreted the set initially.

Answer (score 2):

$x^2 + (2y)^2 \leq 1$. This is the inner part of a deformed circle, ie an ellipse, thus it is path connected and hence connected.

Comment: The definition that we use in class is: "$E$ is *connected* if and only if $E$ cannot  be separated by any pair of relatively open sets $U$, $V$". So I was trying to apply this definition.

Comment: @sinbadh that comment is rude.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is not right, it is like going in circles.

Hint: Proof that the set is convex. Then connected.

Comment: The definition that we use in class is: "$E$ is *connected* if and only if $E$ cannot  be separated by any pair of relatively open sets $U$, $V$". So I was trying to apply this definition.

Comment: Don't you know any other criteria? It looks pretty complicated to prove that with the definition.

Comment: Yotas: I thought that if we can show what I said in my initial post then that would imply that the set is connected.